# Cannot resolve Symbol R (Imported project from Eclipse to Android Studio)

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, r.java-file

I know there have been a lot of people asking this question, and I've read many posts, but none have worked for me...
I updated everything, made sure I have the build tools, most up-to-date SDK etc. and I followed the steps on the Android site for migrating projects from Eclipse to Android Studio.
My project works *fine* in Eclipse, but when I view it in Android Studio, I get the "Cannot resolve symbol R" in my main file.

Does anyone have any insight on this?

Comment: If you modify the id of a view in one of your layouts, that will force Android Studio to rebuild the R file before running. I use this workaround to bypass having to rebuild.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the new version (0.4.3) of the gradle build plugin, that was released yesterday.
More information about this version on g+ [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/108967384991768947849/posts/Me89CcNPB4P).

Answer (score 0):

Update Android Studio. I had the same problem till today. But then I updated the studio and this problem vanished